# Display roles in profile?

Tags: 7, users, entities

I'm trying to display roles in the default user profile (no profile2) with consistent formatting to the other fields being displayed.

In `user-profile.tpl.php` I have this:

```php
<div class="profile"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
    <?php
    // var_dump($user_profile); exit;
    $account = user_load(arg(1));
    $roles = '';
    foreach ($account->roles as $rid => $role) {
        $roles .= "<li>".$role."</li>";
    }
    if (count($roles) > 0) {
        $user_profile['field_user_roles'] = array(
            '#entity_type' => 'custom',
            '#bundle' => 'custom',
            '#theme' => 'field',
            '#field_type' => 'text',
            '#title' => 'Roles',
            '#label_display' => 'above',
            '#field_name' => 'field_user_roles',
            '#markup' => '<ul>' . $roles . '</ul>',
            '#weight' => 5,
        );
    }

     ?>
  <?php print render($user_profile); ?>
</div>
```

Which is giving me this output (which is close):

[image]

The problem is that it doesn't seem to be using `#markup` to display the field.

I'm getting these errors which indicate I'm doing something wrong:

> Notice: Undefined index: #items in template_preprocess_field() (line 1060 of /path/to/site/modules/field/field.module).
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in template_preprocess_field() (line 1060 of /path/to/site/modules/field/field.module).
>
> Notice: Undefined index: #view_mode in zurb_foundation_preprocess_field() (line 311 of /path/to/site/sites/all/themes/zurb_foundation/template.php).

I'm also using the [Foundation Drupal template (v7.5)](https://www.drupal.org/project/zurb_foundation) which seems to relate to the above errors.

Comment: Have you printed a vardump/dpm of $user? If so, please attach result. Also you shouldn't be using `$account = user_load(arg(1));` for security reasons since it uses the URL for the uid. If your user is logged in (which they should be) you can use `global $user;` to load the user's object.

Comment: The `$user` object contains roles as expected, `var_dump`ing the `$roles` array displays the expected results (the roles of the user that is being viewed). Wouldn't `global $user;` only load the user that is logged in, not the user they're viewing (as expected)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Scrolling through the Drupal.org module library, I discovered [Role expose](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_expose). I have never used it, but it seems to do the trick as well:

> Role Expose -module gives site administrators ability to expose user
>   their own user roles. Roles are listed on user profile page. Users may
>   be granted an option to view own roles or all users roles.
>
> [image: Role expose]

**Original answer**

Looking at the render array, I feel you misunderstood a bit (unless you have configured a field on the user object where you already put a string of all his roles, but then you would not need the logic here)...

```
$user_profile['field_user_roles'] = array(
  '#entity_type' => 'custom',          // Nope, it is 'user'.
  '#bundle' => 'custom',               // Nope, it is 'user'.
  '#theme' => 'field',                 // Probably it is not a field, but a custom render element containing markup.
  '#field_type' => 'text',             // Probably not since it probably wasn't a field.
  '#title' => 'Roles',
  '#label_display' => 'above',
  '#field_name' => 'field_user_roles', // Probably not since it probably wasn't a field.
  '#markup' => '<ul>' . $roles . '</ul>',
  '#weight' => 5,
);
```

I guess it works better if you remove some of the data (see below).

On a small side note, logic should be avoided as much as possible within template files. So I'd recommend creating a small custom module and implementing [`hook_user_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_view_alter/7.x). (If you are planning on supporting only one theme, you can also place it in the theme's `template.php` file. Use the theme name as the module name.)

```
function MODULENAME_user_view_alter(&$build) {
  // Obtain the account that user_view() stored for us.
  $account = $build['#account'];

  // Prepare roles string.
  $roles = '';
  foreach ($account->roles as $rid => $role) {
    $roles .= "<li>".$role."</li>";
  }

  if (count($roles) > 0) {
    $build['modulename_user_roles'] = array( // Prefix with module name to prevent collisions.
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#title' => 'Roles',
      '#markup' => '<ul>' . $roles . '</ul>',
      '#attributes' => array('class' => 'class-one class-two'),
    );
  }
}
```

Additionally you can implement [`hook_field_extra_fields()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_extra_fields/7.x) to expose the property on `example.com/admin/config/people/accounts/display` and choose its weight within the admin interface.

```
function MODULENAME_field_extra_fields() {
  $extra['user']['user'] = array(
    'display' => array(
      'modulename_user_roles' => array( // Make sure the name matches your custom property
        'label' => t('User roles'),
        'description' => t("Lists the user's roles."),
        'weight' => 5,
      ),
    )
  );

  return $extra;
}
```

Combined, the property should have been added to the `$user_profile` array and there is no more need to override the template file.

If you want to use the item_list, as [proposed by Yogesh](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/224737/9921), your render array in `MODULENAME_user_view_alter()` should look something like this:

```
    $build['modulename_user_roles'] = array(
      '#title' => 'Roles',
      '#theme' => 'item_list',
      '#items' => $account->roles,
      '#type' => 'ul',
      '#attributes' => array('class' => 'class-one class-two'),
    );
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of explanation and solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to learn it helped you! :)

Comment: One thing -- the "Roles" label isn't showing up on the page, and there's no option for the placement of the label for the field in the 'Manage Display' tab of the user, is there a way to add that in?

Comment: Did you implement the hooks in a custom module and clear the cache?

Comment: Yes, [this is what I'm seeing in 'Manage Display'](http://imgur.com/Gjmybmw), and [on the page](http://imgur.com/0tH18NB). There's not a label showing up on the page or in the display options.

Comment: You should also add `'#type' => 'item'` to the render array. It works now :)

Comment: That did work for getting the 'Roles' label to show on the page, so thanks for that. But is there any way to have this field displayed with the same layout/format/classes as the other fields? [See here for the differences in markup](http://imgur.com/zoLay20)

Comment: Well, it is not a field, so it does not get the same classes a field gets, but you can manually add them: `'#attributes' => array('class' => 'one two three'),`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [theme_item_list](https://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_item_list/7) function to print it in lsit format, check sample below:

```
<div class="profile" <?php print $attributes; ?>>
<?php $account = user_load(arg(1)); ?>
<?php print theme('item_list', array('items' => $account->roles)); ?>
</div>
```

Or you can write your own html like below (not preferred):

```
<div class="profile" <?php print $attributes; ?>>
<?php
  $account = user_load(arg(1));

  // Below code wraps roles in <li> tag.
  $roles = '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $account->roles) . '</li></ul>';
  // Below code show roles separated by comma.
  // $roles = implode(', ', $account->roles);

  print '<ul>' . $roles . '</ul>';
?>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like this would just put the roles under all the other profile fields, right? I was trying to add it to the `$user_profile` array so that it would keep consistent format and styling and I could use `weight` to move it around if needed.

Comment: @Samsquanch, the way I've provided directly prints roles in template file, it won't affect your `$user_profile` styling as it is not modifying or overriding it. If you're looking for re-arranging from UI/weight @neograph734 solution is best suite. As it will add the Roles element to your user profile display and you can then re-arrange it as per your needs.